# SharePoint installing update checklist

Tags: cumulative-update

We want to install June 2015 CU update on our SharePoint 2010 sp2 test environment, we want to then be sure that we passed all tests in our test environment. Is there any test case or checklist that we can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the checklist if any available, but i can tell you some from experience.

- Make sure SharePoint build Number change to new.
- Make Sure all server in farm saying no action required.
- Make Sure All Databases(Content & Services & Config) status must be No Action required.
- Make Sure Time Services & Admin Services IS running on all server.
- App Pools are running on all server.
- make Sure all web apps are up and running.
- Make Sure the all the required Services are running.
- Run the User Profile Crawl.
- Run the Search Crawl.
- Test the Basic operations of SharePoint:

  - Create a new site collection
  - create new subsite
  - add / remove users
  - create new workflow, run the existing workflows.
  - test the alerts.
  - upload file, delete file
  - check in / check out files
  - Publish a page
  - other functionality which you use alot.
- If you an customization, then test it is placed and functionality available. i.e solution deployment, web.config changes etc.